# Is it considered good or bad practice to leave a blank line at the end of a code file?

Tags: optimization

I've seen generators leave a line but I'm sure I've read a blog post stating it's bad practice.

What is the general consensus?

Comment: at the very least gcc issues a warning if there is no newline at end of file

Comment: I believe it have historic reasons. Makes life easier when e.g. using `cat file0.c file1.c file2.c` or something like that. Also worth noting that both vim and emacs adding invisible newline automatically on default settings.

Answer (score 1):

Makes no difference. Put in as many blanks as you like!

Comment: Indentation doesn't make a difference either, yet it's not a good idea to go haywire with it.

Comment: What about 10k+ blank lines? :) taken from real example...

Comment: In terms of compiler optimisation, 10K blanks probably won't make a huge difference. Certainly won't impact the compiled code.

Comment: Impact on the compiled code isn't the only criteria, quite the opposite: It is one of the less important ones in most cases. "Programs must be written for people to read, and only incidentally for machines to execute." (Abelson & Sussman)